# How to set focus in touchableopacity?

Tags: react-native

I developing application for android-tv I need set focus in TouchableOpacity.
How can i do this?
My example of focus detection on Android TV

```
enableTVEventHandler() {
    this.evtHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this.evtHandler.enable(this, this.handleTVRemoteEvent);
}


disableTVEventHandler() {
    if (this.evtHandler) {
        this.evtHandler.disable();
        delete this.evtHandler;
    }
}

handleTVRemoteEvent = (cmp, event) => {
    const { eventType, tag } = event;

    if (tag !== this.nodeHandle) {
        return;
    }

    if (eventType === "focus") {
        this.setState({ isFocus: true });

        if (this.props.focus !== undefined) {
            this.props.focus();
        }
    }

    if (eventType === "blur") {
        this.setState({ isFocus: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by set focus on TouchableOpacity?

Comment: I mean, handleTVRemoteEvent will point to my element

Answer (score 1):

After working for a while i found this solution:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this.props.onPress}
  onFocus={() => {
    this.setState({
      currentStyle: 'blue',
    })
  }}
  onBlur={() => {
    this.setState({
      currentStyle: 'white',
    })
  }}
>
{this.props.children}
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Pressable instead of touchable